# How to implement breadcrumbs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, breadcrumbs

I don't know if this feature that shows list of pages that user has visited and also links them and looks like: Home> News> LogIn... has a particular name or not, but I don't have any idea about implementing it in my website. any help would be appreciated. thnx.

Comment: It is called a **breadcrumb**

Comment: @DidierGhys It sounds like what the OP is looking for is not a breadcrumb, but a history of visited pages. Breadcrumbs typically show where the page is located in the site hierarchy.

Comment: You're right. The question's not just very clear, and the form "Home> News> LogIn.." looks like a typical breadcrumb.

Comment: [jBreadcrumb](http://www.comparenetworks.com/developers/jqueryplugins/jbreadcrumb.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically breadcrumps wouldnt be implemented with jquery.

Breadcrumbs do not change with any action on a page self so its mostly created using the serverside script language.
Im not sure if u use php or .net, but i would look there to create breadcrumbs.

I know zend framework has a very good breadcrump generation based on an navigation xml.

Try googling for breadcrump php or breadcrump .net.